# Mysterious INSERT UPDATE error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like (irrelevant columns subtracted):

```
PRIMARY KEY(AUTO-INCREMENT,INT), 
CLIENTID(INT), 
CLIENTENTRYID(INT), 
COUNT1(INT), 
COUNT2(INT)
```

Now, the CLIENTID and CLIENTENTRYID is a unique combined index serving as a duplication prevention.

I use PHP post input to the server. My query looks like:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare('INSERT INTO table (COUNT1,COUNT2,CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COUNT1=VALUES(COUNT1),COUNT2=VALUES(COUNT2)');

$stmt->bind_param("iiii",$value,$value,$clientid,$cliententryid);
```

The SQL object has auto commit enabled. The "value" variable is reused as the value in COUNT1 and COUNT2 should ALWAYS be the same.

Okay - that works fine, most of the time, but randomly, and I cannot figure out why, it will post 0 in COUNT2 - for an entirely different row.

Any ideas how that might occur? I can't see a pattern (it doesn't happen after a failed attempt, which is why the unique index exists, so that a new attempt will not cause duplicates). It seems to be completely random.

Is there something I've misunderstood about ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? The VERY weird thing is that it updates A DIFFERENT row incorrectly - not the one you insert.

I realize other factors might affect this, but now I'm trying to rule out my SQL logic as a source of error.

Comment: Your logic, and your SQL, look fine to me. I'd suspect something else is changing the data.

Comment: If an `INSERT` statement is going so far off the rails as to change the values in a completely different row then you have *far* larger problems than some PHP code. So... yeah, it's not that. Your logic in diagnosing this problem is equivalent to "every time I start my car my neighbour's blender turns on".

Comment: I realized as much. I was just trying to find out if the unique index somehow could cause this. Let's say another client sends the same unique index for a different row than the one you're trying to update. Then something weird like this might happen.

Comment: No, it really won't. You're not going to end up updating a different row. Assuming you're not using some really old version of MySQL, or anything like that?

Comment: Newest community version.

Well, if a client sends an already existing unique index and the values x and 0 (for count2), then this would update a different row, but then has nothing to do with above query.

Comment: I just checked the entire database for integrity errors. Everything says "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the PRIMARY KEY on the auto_increment column, there is only ONE UNIQUE key defined the table, and that's defined on **`(CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID)`**, right?

And there are no triggers defined on the table, right?

And you are (obviously) using a prepared statement with bind placeholders.

It doesn't really matter if those two columns (CLIENTID and CLIENTENTRYID) are defined as NOT NULL or not; MySQL will allow multiple rows with NULL values; that doesn't violated the "uniqueness" enforced by a UNIQUE constraint. (This the same as how Oracle treats "uniqueness" of NULL values, but it is different from how SQL Server enforces it.)

---

I just don't see any way that the statement you show, that is:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (COUNT1,COUNT2,CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE COUNT1 = VALUES(COUNT1)
     , COUNT2 = VALUES(COUNT2)
```

... theres no way that Would cause some other row in the table to be updated.

Either the insert action succeeds, or it throws a "duplicate key" exception. If the "duplicate key" exception is thrown, the statement catches that, and performs the UPDATE action.

Given that `(CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID)` is the only unique key on the table (apart from the auto_increment column, not referenced by this statement), the update action will be equivalent to this statement:

```
UPDATE `mytable`
   SET COUNT1        = ?
     , COUNT2        = ?
 WHERE CLIENTID      = ?
   AND CLIENTENTRYID = ?
```

... using the values supplied in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement.

Bottom line, there isn't an issue in **anything** OP showed us. The logic is sound. There is **something else** going on, apart from this SQL statement.

OP code shows as using scalars (and not array elements) as arguments in the `bind_param` call, so that whole messiness of passing by reference shouldn't be an issue.

There's not an issue with the SQL statement OP has shown, based on everything OP told us and shown us. The issue reported has to be something **other** than the SQL statement.

Comment: I don't know how to open chat. But: I just tried defining a trigger for "BEFORE UPDATE" that changes a column I added called "MODIFIED" to "NOW()" - it works if I intentionally input a duplicate entry from SQL prompt - and the values are also update correctly. When I see the error occur, the MODIFIED does NOT change, the COUNT2 just jumps to zero for a random row. And yes, this is the only unique column aside from PK.

Comment: Accepted for most thorough and correct answer in relation to information provided by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MySQL [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), it says that given an `insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

if column a and b are unique, the `insert` is equivalent to an `update` statement with a `WHERE` clause containing an `OR` instead of an `AND`:

```
UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1 OR b=2 LIMIT 1;
```

And to quote from the documentation,

> If a=1 OR b=2 matches several rows, only one row is updated. **In
>   general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.**

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

As per further discussion, OP will consider [re-visiting existing database design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25558579/1144203). OP also has another table with similar multiple unique index spec, but without the same problem by utilizing `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: But I don't +1 anything? What should I do if not use multiple unique index? Your last sentence kind of ruins my entire database build.

Comment: It's an iPad that posts the info. The CLIENTID doesn't change, but CLIENTENTRYID is incremented by 1 for every operation, so that the same attempt to update will not cause a duplicate entry. The weird thing is that this doesn't happen after a failed attempt.

Comment: @nickdnk Yeah, I hate to be bearer of bad news. Do you really have to make BOTH `CLIENTID` and `CLIENTENTRYID` unique index? I see that you already have a PK in your table.

Comment: The idea is that the combination makes the entry unique. The client cannot know about the PK as it's just an auto-increment value.
It's a COMBINED unique index, they're not separately unique. This way no client can ever post the same client-clienentryid combination as it's logically impossible.

Comment: @nickdnk Why would your client need to know about the PK? Can you update your insert statement to `INSERT INTO table (ID, COUNT1,COUNT2,CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COUNT1=VALUES(COUNT1),COUNT2=VALUES(COUNT2)');` to ensure the auto-increment PK is inserted for every operation?

Comment: @nickdnk You also mentioned that `CLIENTENTRYID` is incremented for every operation, so yes, it's impossible for a client to post the same client-cliententryid combination. When the client wants to retrieve a row, the client-cliententryid combination provided will still be unique even if you didn't specifically make it a unique index.

Comment: You suggest using the combination as primary key?

Comment: And also INSERT INTO table (ID, COUNT1,COUNT2,CLIENTID,CLIENTENTRYID) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COUNT1=VALUES(COUNT1),COUNT2=VALUES(COUNT2)'); is exactly what I'm doing. Look at OP.

Comment: (since the default value is obsolete. If no value is specified for auto-increase, SQL will automatically increase it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60194/discussion-between-isim-and-nickdnk).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

As everyone here correctly suggested, this was something else. For some completely bizarre reason, the button I used to open the "add new entry" somehow POST'ed to set arrived = 0 on a selected object in a table view that has nothing to do with the button.

This must have been a UI linking somewhere in my Storyboard.

I'm sorry I wasted so much of your time guys. At least I learned a little more about SQL and indexes.

Answer (score -2):

i think problem is with your are using values in  UPDATE COUNT1=VALUES(COUNT1),COUNT2=VALUES(COUNT2) try to use like this 
  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COUNT1 = $v1,COUNT2 = $v2;`

Comment: Using `VALUES()` is correct in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: How would that change the value in a different row? I don't get it.

Comment: It's valid (and preferred) to use the special **`VALUES()`** function like OP does. This usage of the `VALUES()` function is *not* causing the problem reported by OP.